# Why need to create array element with Java Reflection

Tags: java, arrays

Someone will write code like this:

```
int[] intArray = (int[]) Array.newInstance(int.class, 3);
Array.set(intArray, 0, 123);
Array.set(intArray, 1, 456);
Array.set(intArray, 2, 789);
System.out.println("intArray[0] = " + Array.get(intArray, 0));
System.out.println("intArray[1] = " + Array.get(intArray, 1));
System.out.println("intArray[2] = " + Array.get(intArray, 2));
```

I'd like to ask why need I modify an array like this rather than:

intArray[0]=123;

intArray[1]=456;

intArray[2]=789;

Comment: You don't. Why do you thing you need to? Also, `int.class`? Surely you mean `Integer.TYPE`?

Comment: @BoristheSpider `int.class` is legal syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no motivation behind the code you have provided, it could all be replaced by native array syntax. The `Array` class is only useful for a generic treatment of arrays whose component type is not known at compile time.

A simple example could be parsing some wire format, where you may have a helper method such as this:

```
public Object toArray(Class<?> componentType, int size, Parser p) {
   Object array = Array.newInstance(componentType, size);
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
      Arrays.set(array, i, p.nextItem());
   return array;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example, please?

Comment: I have provided an example with a helper method used while parsing.

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to ask why need I modify an array like this ...

You normally don't need to do it like that.  And if you don't need to, you shouldn't!

But suppose you were writing code to create and initialize arbitrary Java data structures based on descriptions in (for example) XML or JSON.  In that case, you might write reflective code that did that kind of thing ... in a more generic fashion ... to construct the data structures.